# I need help with vectors...

Tags: vectors

Given that $OA=(-7,25)$ and $OB=(4,5)$, then find:

$a.$ The unit vector parallel to $AB$.

$b.$ The vector OC such that $AC=3AB$

Comment: Welcome to the site. It would be prudent to learn a math based subscript language like LaTeX. This way you can make proper professional work where Mathematics is concerned. Also it is very helpful to know what trials and errors you have made. This way we can better assess your capabilities and act accordingly. Ergo "What have you tried?"

Comment: @DMcMor you might want to embolden the vector $OC$. this will cause less confusion later.

Comment: In addition to @Sentinel135 , I would suggest you to read [tour] page and [ask] too.

Comment: People, please don't downvote and discourage a new user just because the don't know how this website works.Give them some time to understand.

Comment: @JaideepKhare Fair enough, but it's now nine hours with no response to "what have you tried" (or any other response, for that matter). Given the complete lack of any indication that the new user _has any interest_ in learning how this website works, I'm voting to close. If the question closes, the user can always put in the effort people asked for and try to get the question reopened.

Comment: @DavidK I completely agree (Even I'm gonna vote to close this question) . I added that comment because there was a downvote in nearly  2 minutes after the question was posted.Even I am removing my upvote (Which I did to counter the downvote)

Comment: @JaideepKhare I agree that it is harsh to downvote a new user only two minutes after they posted. I prefer your approach: start with a comment directing the OP toward better use of the site, and take other action later if that doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

$a)$ We have: $\vec{u} = \dfrac{\vec{AB}}{|\vec{AB}|}=\left(\dfrac{11}{\sqrt{11^2+20^2}},\dfrac{-20}{\sqrt{11^2+20^2}}\right)=\left(\dfrac{11}{\sqrt{521}}, \dfrac{-20}{\sqrt{521}}\right)$

$b)$ We have: $\vec{AC} = 3\vec{AB}\implies x_c-(-7) = 3(4-(-7)), y_c - 25 = 3(5-25)\implies x_c = 26, y_c = -35\implies \vec{OC} = (26,-35)$.